# DOM Elements accessibility in ASP.NET MVC and ASCX

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I have a complex asp.net mvc view where I load an "ascx" partial view into a `div` using `$.ajax()`. So I was wondering about the accessibility of the DOM elements contained in the main page and the ascx partial view. Using jQuery selectors, can I find an element in the main page from  the ascx partial view? and the other way round?

Answer (score 2):

Both ways, depending on the point on time.

You can always access the elements from the main view, since the HTML is bound at render-time (e.g `$(document).ready()`)

You won't be access the elements in the partial view from the parent view until the callback from the `$.ajax` method has completed successfully and you have binded the HTML to the DOM (with `.html(result)` for example).